# Manipulate Canvas content

Tags: javascript, jquery

EDIT: Found the information needed here:
http://tutorials.jenkov.com/html5-canvas/todataurl.html

i am using the Szimek's signature pad script. It's pretty neat and what i'm trying to do is to store the image base64 correspondent code at my db.

Problem is , i can't handle the code created in any way. This is what makes the signature show in a new window:

> window.open(signaturePad.toDataURL());

You can try it yourself here:
http://szimek.github.io/signature_pad/

What i would like is to keep the data from the signature inside a value, to later manipulate.

Hope i made myself clear! Thank you very much to all of you!!

Comment: just don't pass it to window.open, pass it to your saver.

Comment: @dandavis, yes, but i didn't knew how to manage the canvas content.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the inconvenience, the solution was pretty simple:

```
var dataUrl = signaturePad.toDataURL();
$("#assinatura").html(dataUrl);
```

Changed this "window.open(signaturePad.toDataURL());" to the above. Now just need to store the content of the div.

Thank you once again!

Cheers.